# Select fails to print to console

Tags: c#, linq, select

I was hoping to use `Select` as a functional foreach. When I do the following, I expected it to print

```
foo
bar
baz
```

it doesn't print anything however. Howcome? The code is

```
List<String> strings = new List<String>(){"foo", "bar", "baz"};
strings.Select(st => { Console.WriteLine(st); return 1; });
```

Comment: You don't really enumerate with `Select`.

Comment: Select defers execution until the results are actually needed.

Comment: Select projects each element of a sequence into a new form, i.e. you use it to convert the collection elements to another type.

Comment: +1 to Gert and jrajva. Try adding `.ToList()` after the `Select`

Comment: @JensKloster: Or `Count()`, which will avoid actually creating a new list...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use ForEach**:

```
List<String> strings = new List<String>() { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
strings.ForEach(st => { Console.WriteLine(st);  });
```

By using Select you're basically defining anonymous functions with the following body.

```
Console.WriteLine(st); 
return 1;
```

So, Console.WriteLine will only be triggered when you're iterating through the list, like this:

```
var x= strings.Select(st => { Console.WriteLine(st); return 1; });

foreach (var i in x){ }
```

or `x.ToList()`

And that is wrong, use ForEach :)

Comment: how on earth did I not notice that was there? Could you add to the answer that the result is not enumerated, and it would be with an extra call toList();?

Comment: Ah, I now see how I missed this. While List<T> exposes foreach, IEnumerable<T> for some reason doesn't.

Comment: @Martijn I think you initial confusion is part of _some reason_ :)

Comment: @Gert Not exposing ForEach so people start to resort to Select and mess it up is not really a good reason

Comment: Can we not simply use: strings.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); ?